# Solution for ODE $-au'' + \vert u' \vert -1 = 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

someone help-me find a solution of this ODE:

$$
-au''(x) + \vert u'(x) \vert -1 = 0,\quad x\in (-1,1)
\\
u(-1)=u(1) = 0 
$$
with a>0.

The book say that solution is
$$
u(x) = 1-\vert x\vert +ae^{-1/a}(1- e^{(1-\vert x \vert)/a})
$$

I try this

$$
u(x) = e^{rx}
\\
u'(x) = re^{rx}
\\
u''(x)=r^2e^{rx}
$$
But, after manipulation I not  got sucess...

Comment: using the the solution $u = \mathrm{e}^{rx}$ does not satisfy the initial condition $u(-1) = u(1) = 0$

Answer (score 1):

An almost trivial sub:
$$
-au'' +|u'| -1 = 0 \implies -ap' +|p| -1 = 0
$$
can you proceed from here?

Comment: Hi, thanks, I'm still confuse to solve modulus, this sub helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more details about the solution? I'm still confuse.

I try this, for $p>0$

$$
p = c_1e^{x/a} +1
\\
\text{so}
\\
u'(x) = c_1e^{x/a}+1
\\
u(x) = c_1ae^{x/a} +x +c_2
$$